# Convert pgm image to bmp

Tags: c#, bmp, pgm

how do I load pgm image in C# and how Im convert it to pgm file?

Comment: Search Google; hopefully this link will be useful http://www.codeding.com/?article=3

Answer (score 1):

I found a blog entry that has the code to convert a PGM file to a BMP file for you.  I had to use Google Translate to read the page, but the code listed is in English and it looks good.  Here is the link (using translate):

http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://kb.cnblogs.com/a/1266417/&ei=fkbmTYqRMoe4twfq_PDeCg&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CFAQ7gEwBQ&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dc%2523%2Bconvert%2Bpgm%26hl%3Den%26prmd%3Divns

Basically, just copy and paste this code.  The `BitmapToBitmap()` method is what you want to call.